# How to remove a "system property" in Jenkins via Script Console

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkins it is possible to customise/parameterise the application with so called "System Properties". In the console you can manage to set properties like the following:

`System.setProperty("hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.forceLdaps", "true")`

With the code of `println` and `System.getProperty` it is possible to see the value, which in this case is `true`. You can also view this on the page itself when navigating to `/systemInfo` in the URL.

Is it possible to remove the System Property by code? I searched the documentation of [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/) but no luck. [Another topic I found](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source-Questions/How-do-I-remove-a-global-property-from-a-Groovy-script/td-p/29137) with the same problem is dead since 2012-2013.

I tried the following, unfortunately without success:

1. `System.getProperty("hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.forceLdaps").remove()`
2. `System.removeProperty("hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.forceLdaps")`
3. `System.setProperty("hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.forceLdaps", null)`
4. `System.setProperty("hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.forceLdaps", undefined)`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem by myself:

You can use `System.clearProperty(String key)` to remove the System Parameter, the option I didn't used before.

Hopefully this can be a good use for other people.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you added the property via Script Console, restarting Jenkins would remove it.

```
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```